# angularjs: ng-model-options can only take an inline hash when in a directive, is this a bug?

Tags: angularjs

This works fine inside controllers and directives :

```
<input ng-model="customerInfo.name" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}">
```

If inside of a directive, instead of passing an inline hash, I give ng-model-options a reference to a hash in the scope, like this :

```
scope.options = {updateOn: 'blur'}

<input ng-model="customerInfo.name" ng-model-options="options">
```

I get :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateOn' of undefined
```

Is this a bug ?

### update, here's a plunker that shows the problem :

http://plnkr.co/edit/hLDlwstqrFiGDfrgn1Mh?p=preview

### solution:

I ended up seting the options in compile/pre

```
  compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
    return {
      pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
        scope.moptions = {updateOn: 'blur'}
      },
      post: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: $scope.options = {"updateOn": 'blur'};

Comment: can you show more of your code ??

Comment: @jackk quotes are optional on javascript object keys that don't contain special characters

Comment: provide a demo that replicates problem

Comment: I posted a plunker that shows the problem

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug. ng-model-options directive is executed even before the link function of the custom directive is run [This is the execution order]. So the object is not set in scope.

Better option would be make the directive inline with ng-options and give higher priority

```
//html
<input my-directive ng-model="myObject.name" ng-model-options="options">

//directive
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: true,
    priority: 1000,
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.myObject = {};
      $scope.options = {
        updateOn: 'blur'
      };

    }
  };
})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/XUViTS4Jfc8RoLWRFfzv?p=preview

You would have to set object in parent scope 
http://plnkr.co/edit/sTXLo2IYsUW75FeCJCZW?p=preview

```
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.options = {
      updateOn: 'blur'
    };
  }])
  .directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'my-directive.html',
      link: function(scope) {
        scope.myObject = {}

      }
    };
  })
```

or you would have to pass it as scope attribute 
 http://plnkr.co/edit/sTXLo2IYsUW75FeCJCZW?p=preview